# grouping dictionary with list values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where lists are values.  I would like to filter the data based on certain values within lists.  For example. . .

```
inventory = {'A':['Toy',3], 'B':['Toy',8], 'C':['Cloth',15], 'D':['Cloth',9], 'E':['Toy',11]}
```

I would like to create another dictionary where it only shows the top priced item such that it will be. . .

```
inventoryFiltered = {'C':['Cloth',15], 'E':['Toy',11]}
```

What code should I use to convert inventory into inventoryFiltered?

The end result should have top priced for each merchandise item type (such as 'Cloth', 'Toy', 'Electronic', 'Food', 'Shoes')

I only have these modules available for my system.

```
bisect
cmath
collections
datetime
functools
heapq
itertools
math
numpy
pandas
pytz
Queue
random
re
scipy
statsmodels
sklearn
talib
time
zipline
```

Further, I would like to accomplish one more step.  Say I have one more data element (I am adding the item's days in inventory (how many days it was on the store or storage).

```
inventory = {'A':['Toy',3, 30], 'B':['Toy',8, 40], 
    'C':['Cloth',15, 50], 'D':['Cloth',9, 60], 'E':['Toy',11, 70]}.
```

I would like it to do the exact same thing. But keep the last element (days in inventory)

```
inventoryFiltered = {'C':['Cloth',15, 50], 'E':['Toy',11, 70]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort on the items of the dictionary:

```
inventory = {
    'A': ['Toy', 3, 30],
    'B': ['Toy', 8, 80],
    'C': ['Cloth', 15, 150],
    'D': ['Cloth', 9, 90],
    'E': ['Toy', 11, 110]
}

items = sorted(inventory.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])

most_expensive_by_category = {item[0]: (key, item) for key, item in items}

most_expensive = dict(most_expensive_by_category.values())
```

Result:

```
{'C': ['Cloth', 15, 150], 'E': ['Toy', 11, 110]}
```

With `items = sorted(inventory.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][1])` we sort the items of input dictionary by price. Because of the sort order, `most_expensive_by_category` construction will keep only the most expensive item for a specific category.

Comment: Super.  Do you mind explaining to me what _: _[1][1] and [:2] is doing?  I need to apply this logic to a more complex dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.  However, can [:2] modified?  Because my real dataset can have 'toy', 'cloth', 'music', 'electronics' .... meaning it is variable and many.  So [:2] won't work for me.  If I have 'toy', 'cloth', 'music' then I need [:3].  I never know how many unique item will show up

Comment: You mean you want the top price for each category? If yes, then I answered wrong question :) Can you clarify it in the question?

Comment: JuniorCompressor, you are right.  Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: JuniorCompressor, I just updated my original question. Does the change make the solution more difficult?

Answer (score 1):

I would first invert the dictionary like so:

```
inv={}
for k, li in inventory.items():
    inv.setdefault(li[0], []).append([k, li[1]])

>>> inv
{'Cloth': [['C', 15], ['D', 9]], 'Toy': [['A', 3], ['B', 8], ['E', 11]]}
```

Then getting the max of any category is trivial:

```
>>> max(inv['Cloth'], key=lambda l: l[1])
['C', 15]
>>> max(inv['Toy'], key=lambda l: l[1])
['E', 11]
>>> {k:max(inv[k], key=lambda l: l[1]) for k,v in inv.items()}
{'Cloth': ['C', 15], 'Toy': ['E', 11]}
```

If you have a second element, like days of age, just use that in the max key value.

Comment: Thank you.  But can you do such way so that I can get the not just max, but top two or three?   And if I only have one data element, I would like to drop it.

Comment: Just sort and slice rather than use the `max` function.